# Interrupt setTimeout countdown if condition is met after it has started in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, bots, discord

I am trying to make a trivial bot for discord. I have a working system where a random question from an array is asked when a user inputs a message starting with '?trivial' and the corresponding answer from the list is given after 5 seconds. Now I want to make the countdown stop if the correct answer is given by any user while the countdown is running, and display a message. This is what I tried, but it doesn't work, giveing the correct answer doesn't give an error but simply nothing happens and the countdown continues until it reaches its natural end.

```
if (message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "trivial")) {
 var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Questions.length);
 if(number % 2 == 0){
number = number;
} else
number = number +1
var question = Questions[number];
var answer = Questions[number +1]; 
message.channel.send(question);
function giveanswer(){
message.channel.send("Correct Answer: " + answer) 
}
myVar = setTimeout (giveanswer, 5000)
if (message.content.startsWith('answer')){
  clearTimeout (myVar);
  message.channel.send('Congrats!')
  }
}
```

I have tried this and a few other similar variations but I'm starting to think I am not on the right track at all.

Comment: `if (message.content.startsWith('answer')){` did you mean to check against the literal string `"answer"` or against the string contained in the variable `answer`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This code is ran when anyone in the discord server writes '?trivial' (it is part of the code for a bot which has other games inside it as well), which works fine. It is meant to check against the string contained in the variable 'answer'.

Comment: Then you need to remove the quotes around it, ie `startsWith(answer)`

Comment: Also every time someone enters something other than `?trivial` you are changing your `question` and `answer`

Comment: True! Thanks! However I've changed it and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I have one more question tho - if anyone entering something other than ?trivial changes the question and answer, why does the giveanswer function still work and return the right answer after the 5 seconds have run out, regardless of how what anyone has written in the meantime?